# Can't find Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll assembly file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies, smo, add-references-dialog

I'm trying to dynamically get a databases Table structure using only C# code as follows:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

public class LoadStuff
{
    ...
    public void LoadDatabase(string vDatabaseName)
    {
        using (var vSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            var vConnection = new ServerConnection(vSqlConnection);
            var vServer = new Server(vConnection);
            var vDatabase = vServer.Databases[vDatabaseName];
            var vTables = vDatabase.Tables;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot find the .dll file to add a reference too. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is located in c:\program files\microsoft sql server\xxx\sdk\assemblies on my machine.  Where xxx is the SQL Server version number (90 or 100).  Not sure how it got there.

Comment: Found it, thanks. Now, when an end user runs this, is this referenced .dll file going to be bundled into my software?

Comment: Doubtful.  Set Copy Local to True so it is copied to your build directory, ready to be included in your Setup project.

Comment: What do I need install to get assemblies?

Answer (score 8):

Please right click your solution and select 'Add reference' and then select the following dlls:

- C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO
- C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
- C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.sfc

Comment: This didn't work for me, but was a good hint. I ended up installing these via NuGet. Right click on Refernces, Manage NuGet Packages, search for Microsoft.sqlserver. then install the Microsoft.SqlServer.* DLL's of interest.  (Feb 2016, Visual Studio 2015 Pro Update 1)

Answer (score 1):

On my machine it is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`. As an alternative, you can also download the standalone installation from the SQL Server [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=228DE03F-3B5A-428A-923F-58A033D316E1&displaylang=en) or [2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ceb4346f-657f-4d28-83f5-aae0c5c83d52&displaylang=en) feature packs. There are individual x86 and x64 installation packages available.

Comment: Do I need install Sql Server 2008 Express ?