# Where can I find a SQL Server Management Objects Collection for SQL Server Express?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express, smo

I have written an application that works fine  when run from Visual Studio 2017, and uses the following libraries:

- `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common`
- `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`

But when I try to run it stand alone, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or  assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Which I traced down to missing SQL Server Management Objects collection for the SQL Server.

I need to know how to resolve this, or if it can be resolved for SQL Server Express. I noticed these packs are available for install for the purchased SQL Server versions, but have found nothing for Express.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556379/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-connectioninfo-dll-assembly-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install **SQLSysClrTypes.msi**

UPDATED LINK
https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/3/0/13089488-91FC-4E22-AD68-5BE58BD5C014/ENU/x86/SQLSysClrTypes.msi

... and maybe reboot your S.O

*SQL = Structured Query Language  ( sequel is just phonetics or a DB tool for Ruby )*

OLD LINK
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188392&clcid=0x409

When you said "compiled executable", did you take the .exe, all .dll and all other files from bin folder?  Please, copy entire content of your bin folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Installed and rebooted. Still got the same error.  it works when I launch it from Visual Studio 2017, but if I take that compiled executable and launch it on it's own, I get that error. I have no idea why, because it's using the libraries from my sequel installation.

Comment: Ok, maybe you have another common issue.  Are you using Entity framework?  When you said "compiled executable",  did you take the .exe, all .dll and all other   files from bin folder?

Comment: Using .NET Framework 4.6.1, not using Unity Framework. It's only a single executable, no dll's.

Comment: Please, note that I mentioned "Entity framework" and not Unity. Could you please add the line in your code that throws the error?

Comment: Not using Entity Framework.    posting function below.

Comment: omg. you were right. I didn't realize that visual studio copied the DLL's directly to the bin\Release folder and so it worked in visual studio. I just have to copy those DLL's. Assuming they are licensed as redistributable.

Comment: Great! That's because I'm very old :P .

Answer (score 0):

This is the function. 
DBServerTextBox.Text is @"localhost\SQLEXPRESS”
DBDataTextBox.Text is the path to the DATA directory
The label refreshes and Thread sleep is so I can see the lable messages before they flash past.

```
private void AttachDatabaseToInstance()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + DBServerTextBox.Text + @";Initial Catalog=master;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User ID=dbadmin;Password=dbadmin";

        ServerConnection serverconn = new ServerConnection(con);
        Server s = new Server(serverconn);

        try
        {
            con.Close();
            InstallStatusLabel.Text = "Existing connections closed";
            InstallStatusLabel.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            s.DetachDatabase("mydatabase", true);
            InstallStatusLabel.Text = "Detaching any existing mydatabase database";
            InstallStatusLabel.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find attached database");
        }
        try
        {
            s.AttachDatabase("mydatabase", new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection { DBDataTextBox.Text + @"\mydatabase.mdf", DBDataTextBox.Text + @"\mydatabase_log.ldf" }, AttachOptions.None);
            InstallStatusLabel.Text = "Attached mydatabase database";
            InstallStatusLabel.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```